# Purchasing Static Public IP Address

Tags: ip

If a company purchases a static Public IP address in an IP registry org such as APNIC, will the company be able to use it regardless of change in ISP?

Do the company shows the certificate of registration to ISP that we purchased this IP? so configure this for our use?

Answer (score 2):

The smallest possible address range that can be obtained directly from APNIC is /24 for IPv4 (i.e. 256 addresses), and /48 for IPv6.

This is also the smallest possible address range that can be announced world-wide using BGP – most ISPs will simply ignore smaller announcements.

This means that smaller ranges (such as single addresses) can *only* be obtained from an ISP and are always tied to that ISP's network; they do not become yours when "purchased".

> If a company purchases a static Public IP address in an IP registry org such as APNIC, will the company be able to use it regardless of change in ISP?

If the addresses were obtained *directly* from the registry (i.e. your company itself is a LIR), then yes, you can announce them via BGP through any ISP (or ISPs) that lets you.

If they were obtained indirectly, through delegation from an ISP, then no – the APNIC policy specifically says that "Delegations are non-portable and must be returned to the LIR if the downstream customer ceases to receive connectivity from the LIR".

However, it should still be fine to announce the same IP addresses through *multiple* ISPs, as long as the original ISP is among them. See also [this blog post](https://blog.apnic.net/2014/09/22/multihoming-design-options-with-portable-ip-address-pros-and-cons/).

> Do the company shows the certificate of registration to ISP that we purchased this IP?

ISPs can look up this information on APNIC's 'Whois' database. (However, I don't know what documents they require in practice.)

> so configure this for our use?

Most commonly, if you "own" the addresses, then your own routers have to announce them using the BGP protocol – ISPs then propagate this announcement world-wide. Your ISP doesn't configure the addresses directly, but only prepares to accept the advertisement from your router.

(There are exceptions where the ISP also handles the initial announcement, e.g. if you own some addresses but for some reason don't have an AS number from APNIC, I guess?)

---

In response to wk.'s post:

> You can't carry single IPv4 address to other ISP. Routing in TCP/IP is based on networks, not on certain single addresses.

Routing in IP can handle single addresses perfectly fine; a /32 single-address network is no different from any other network size (and that includes BGP, which has no issues carrying /32 or /128 routes).

Rather, ISPs reject such routes as a *policy decision* and enforce it through filtering.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my answer!

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification. that answered my question well

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't carry single IPv4 address to other ISP. Routing in TCP/IP is based on networks, not on certain single addresses.

Comment: ok let us say, it's a multiple ip? my company has purchased a public ip address from APNIC.. i am curious how they able to use the ip as is, even changing multiple ISPs already.. please enlighten me .. thanks

Comment: @joeprick This is Q & A site, here you ask question and award those who answer. If you have more questions, you ask them as separate questions. And you may refer to those in  comments.